# Why would my site start creating locked MySQL processes?

Tags: 7

I am working on a Drupal 7 development site, and had not installed any additional modules for a couple of weeks.

I was working creating a view to display a list of custom content, and suddenly everything went slow. I soon realised that the site had started creating locked processes and was basically eating all the available memory and MySQL resources, and I was no longer able to view admin/content or run cron.  I had to manually kill the processes to get the server working again.

Any idea on where to start trying to work out why this has happened?   I am using MyISAM, and I understand that this can cause some performance issues on larger sites - but this was a development site that only I am looking at!

For example, this is from my MySQL process log:

`634    tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   1655    statistics  SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression FROM dpnode node INNER JOIN dptaxonomy_`

`657    tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   1593    Locked  SELECT 1 AS expression FROM dphistory history WHERE ( (uid = '1') AND (nid = '267') ) FOR UPDATE`

`868    tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   1108    Locked  SELECT * FROM 'dphistory'`

`902    tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   1056    Locked  SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression FROM dpnode node INNER JOIN dptaxonomy_`

`918    tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   993 Locked  SELECT 1 AS expression FROM dphistory history WHERE ( (uid = '1') AND (nid = '267') ) FOR UPDATE`

`1141   tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   198 Locked  SELECT timestamp FROM dphistory WHERE uid = '1' AND nid = '267'`

`1142   tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   185 Locked  SELECT timestamp FROM dphistory WHERE uid = '1' AND nid = '267'`

`1184   tavata_usr  localhost   tavata_db   Query   73  Locked  SELECT timestamp FROM dphistory WHERE uid = '1' AND nid = '267'`

ETA:
OK, the way I dealt with this was to restart the MySQL server to get rid of all the locked processes and the general eating of my system resources.  Then I went straight to https://example.com/admin/modules  and turned off everything apart from the core modules.

This fixed my problem, although of course half my site stopped working.

I then turned things back on, until I worked out that there was something about the View I had been working on that was causing everything to fall over and lock up.  I am still not sure what, but I'm going to go back and rebuild that view from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As we all know, MyISAM does table level locking and InnoDB does row level locking so it is recommended to use InnoDB storage engine for MySQL.

Secondly, If you generate a block within Views, you can make use of this block cache from the "block caching" option in View UI. You can also use [Views content cache](https://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) mdoule to improve the performance of views. Please refer to below links for more details,

http://www.millwoodonline.co.uk/blog/drupal-7-performance-gains-with-views-cache
http://2bits.com/caching/overcoming-long-views-rendering-time-drupal-sites.html

Comment: This wasn't really a performance issue as such - it was a site that only one user was looking at, that was none the less within a couple of queries managing to permanently lock up all the (fairly generous) resources of the entire server. 
I'll have a look at the caching tools when the time comes to make this live, thanks - block caching certainly looks useful! I do plan to move to InnoDB too, but this particular problem was something else!